# Oracle Database error: ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed

Tags: python, oracle

Aforementioned is the error I have been getting when I m trying to connect my python with Oracle.

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect("username/password@IP:PORT/xe")
```

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed

I have a doubt about the service name "xe". When I change it to "orclpdb". It gives the same error. Please help me sort this.

Comment: `xe` is the name of database for Oracle Express (i.e., free version of the database). Is this correct?

Comment: yes! it is correct. I am using 11ge @Parfait

Comment: Did you ever connect before and it stopped working? Did you research your error in docs or Google/Bing? Check content and permissions of the *tnsnames.ora* file.

Comment: Firewall issue?